# Virtualhost en Apache 2.4 (Windows)

Tags: php, php7, apache, xampp, apache2

trabajo con windows y después de tener muchos problemas con Xaamp he decidido instalar y configurar apache2.4 + mysql + php 7.3 por separado. 
Además he instalado un certificado local , ya que unas de las aplicaciones con la que trabajo es un laravel y necesito SSL porque uso oauth.

Si accedo a uno de los virtualhost me funciona correctamente, el fichero de vhost que tengo es el siguiente

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/dietas_backend/public"
ServerName dietas.local
ServerAlias www.dietas.local
ErrorLog "logs/dietas-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dietas-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/dietas_backend/public"
    ServerName dietas.local
    ServerAlias dietas.local
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/crt/pc.local/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/crt/pc.local/server.key"
    ErrorLog "logs/dietas-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dietas-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/dietas_backend/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/albaran/"
    ServerName albaran.local
    ServerAlias www.albaran.local
    ErrorLog "logs/albaran-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/albaran-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/coches/"
    ServerName coches.local
    ServerAlias www.coches.local
    ErrorLog "logs/coches.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/coches.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Como podéis ver los 2 primeros elementos son "dietas.local" uno por http y el otro en ssl.
Luego abajo tengo 2 virtualhost más que uso que són "albaran.local" y "coches.local"

Si accedo a cualquiera de esas URL me funciona correctamente.

Ahora el problema que tengo un pequeño proyecto en la raiz de mi "htdocs" que tiene esta ruta c:\Apache24\htdocs\pruebas\enviar.php

Con lo que intento acceder mediante http://localhost/pruebas/enviar.php y me envia al virtualhost del LARAVEL.

Aquí esta mi pregunta, veis algo mal en la configuración de las vhost o es de la config del apache?

En la configuración de apache algunos parámetros del fichero que veo son estos.

```
Define SRVROOT "C:/Apache24"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 127.0.0.1:80

ServerName localhost:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
  Allowoverride All
  #Require all denied
  order allow,deny
  allow from all  
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando utilizas Name-based Virtual Host apache busca el vhost que coincida con ServerName o ServerAlias y si no encuentra ninguno que coincida concretamente entonces utiliza el primer vhost que esta definido, en tu caso es `dietas.local`.

Lo que debes hacer es definir un primer vhost por defecto que sirva todas las peticiones que no pertenezcan a ningun vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#  Virtual Host por defecto
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/dietas_backend/public"
ServerName dietas.local
ServerAlias www.dietas.local
ErrorLog "logs/dietas-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dietas-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/dietas_backend/public"
    ServerName dietas.local
    ServerAlias dietas.local
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/crt/pc.local/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/crt/pc.local/server.key"
    ErrorLog "logs/dietas-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dietas-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/dietas_backend/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/albaran/"
    ServerName albaran.local
    ServerAlias www.albaran.local
    ErrorLog "logs/albaran-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/albaran-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/coches/"
    ServerName coches.local
    ServerAlias www.coches.local
    ErrorLog "logs/coches.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/coches.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, funcionando a la perfección.